# Metal. Why does setting MTLCullMode to none turn off depth comparison?

Tags: ios, metal, depth-buffer

I an rendering a simple box:

```
MDLMesh(boxWithExtent: ...)
```

In my draw loop when I turn off back-face culling:

```
renderCommandEncoder.setCullMode(.none)
```

All depth comparison is disabled and sides of the box are drawn completely wrong with back-facing quads in front of front-facing.

Huh?

My intent is to **include** back-facing surfaces in the depth comparison **not** ignore them. This is important for when I have, for example, a shape with semi-transparent textures that reveal the shape's internals which have a different shading style. How to I force depth comparison?

### UPDATE

So Warren's suggestion is an improvement but it is still not correct.

My `depthStencilDescriptor`:

```
let depthStencilDescriptor = MTLDepthStencilDescriptor()
depthStencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = .less
depthStencilDescriptor.isDepthWriteEnabled = true

depthStencilState = device.makeDepthStencilState(descriptor: depthStencilDescriptor)
```

Within my draw loop I set depth stencil state:

```
renderCommandEncoder.setDepthStencilState(depthStencilState)
```

The resultant rendering
[image]

Description. This is a box mesh. Each box face uses a shader the paints a disk texture. The texture is transparent outside the body of the disk. The shader paints a red/white spiral texture on front-facings quads and a blue/black spiral texture on back-facing quads. The box sits in front of a camera aligned quad textured with a mobil image.

Notice how one of the textures paints over the rear back-facing quad with the background texture color. Notice also that the rear-most back-facing quad is not drawn at all.

Comment: How is your `MTLDepthStencilState` configured? This works correctly for me in a test project using the `.less` function and `isDepthWriteEnabled` set to `true`. Make sure you're setting the depth-stencil state on your render command encoder before you issue your draw calls.

Comment: So your suggestion is an improvement but it is still not correct. See my updated question.

Comment: A thought: Do I need to do my own compositing within my fragment shader reading the color attachment and handling the transparency issues directly in the shader?

Comment: @warrenm ironically, isDepthWriteEnabled solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not possible to achieve the effect I am after. I basically want to do a simple composite - Porter/Duff - here but that is order dependent. Order cannot be guaranteed here so I am basically hosed.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was blending happening. It's true that you'll need to draw from back to front if you want proper compositing with antialiasing, but if you can handle a lack of antialiasing and all fragments are either fully opaque or fully transparent, you can use `discard_fragment()` to prevent the transparent fragments from hitting the depth buffer.